# iOS: Export color data to png

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a way to convert my color data into png file. I have color data both in RGBA and HSVA format (a `Double` from 0 to 1 for each component) for each pixel. Now I want to convert that into an actual png, does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have some data array with colour data for each pixel of the image.
You can make a `CGImage` out of that, with `CGImageCreate`.

Then you can use the `CGImageDestination` and `CGImageDestinationAddImage` to write the PNG representation.
Or wrap the `CGImage` in a `UIImage`, and use its `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.